# Task with local extreme

Tags: calculus

I don't know where and what to start calculating in the following task:

Determine the value of parameters $a,b$, so that the function $f(x) = x^3- 2ax + b$ has a local extreme $y=5$ at $x=1$.

The solution is: $a=3/2$, $b=7$

I need to solve quite a few similar tasks as this and I would really appreciate if sb could tell me how to solve it, so I could solve other similar ones.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: HINT: You need to make $f'(1)=0$ and $f(1)=5$. It makes two equations in two variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about how you find local extrema of a function $f(x)$: you find $f\,'(x)$, set it to $0$, and solve to find critical points, which you then examine to see what kinds they are. Do the same here: $f(x)=x^3-2ax+b$, so $f\,'(x)=3x^2-2a$. Setting that to $0$ and solving, you should find that

$$x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2a}3}\;.\tag{a}$$

You want $y=f(x)$ to have a local extrema at $x=1$, so set $x$ to $1$ and solve $(1)$ for $a$. Once you’ve done that, substitute $x=1$ into $f(x)$ and see what value of $b$ will make $f(1)=5$; you’ll know $a$ at that point, so $b$ will be the only unknown, and you will be able to solve for it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: If $x = 1$ implies that $y = 5$, we see that

$$1 - 2a + b = 5$$

Now use the fact that, at a local extreme point, the derivative $f'(x)$ is zero.